# Posting a form to a WebAPI OData controller using an Untyped model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an untyped model in my edm defined like so:

```
<EntityType Name="Content">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
  <Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>
```

When i try to submit a request from an html form the IEdmEntityObject in my POST action is null.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(IEdmEntityObject entity)
```

This works fine with json - the entity comes filled with the properties, but the odata deserializer doesn't seem to understand of application/x-www-form-urlencoded mime-type

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/api/odata/content">
    Title:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Title" value="Mouse">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WebApi OData doesn't support this format, you can check the code https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataMediaTypeFormatters.cs
and spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/odata-json-format-v4.0.html

Or you can customize the formatter, it maybe hard, but any further question or request can open issue in github https://github.com/OData/WebApi